# ¿Cómo hago para que me imprima el total sumando todos los precios y no asi = $ 031983198?

Tags: php, javascript, html5

Estoy trabajando con una función en JavaScript lo que quiero hacer es ir sumando en total la variable precio. Mi problema es que me imprime todos los precios, no los va sumando y al final imprime uno solo. Si yo coloco el precio directo si me los suma, pero si uso:

```
precioo=document.getElementById('dobleentre').value;
```

me imprime todo.

```js
 function difDias(fechaA, fechaB) {
return Math.round(Math.abs(fechaA.getTime() - fechaB.getTime())/(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))
}
      function diferencia(){
var intermedios = "";
var dias_semana=[];
var dias="";
var precioo=0;
var total=0;
dias_semana[0]="Domingo";
dias_semana[1]="Lunes";
dias_semana[2]="Martes";
dias_semana[3]="Miercoles";
dias_semana[4]="Jueves";
dias_semana[5]="Viernes";
dias_semana[6]="Sábado";
var f1 = document.getElementById('inicial').value.split("/");
var d1 = new Date(f1[2],f1[1]-1,f1[0]);
var f2 = document.getElementById('final').value.split("/");
var d2 = new Date(f2[2],f2[1]-1,f2[0]);
var dias_entre =difDias(d1,d2)-1;
 
for (var i=1; i <= dias_entre; i++){
var nd =    new Date(f1[2],f1[1]-1,f1[0]);
nd.setDate(nd.getDate()+ i); 
if (dias_semana[nd.getDay()]=="Domingo" || dias_semana[nd.getDay()]=="Lunes" || dias_semana[nd.getDay()]=="Martes" || dias_semana[nd.getDay()]=="Miercoles") {
  precioo=document.getElementById('dobleentre').value;
 }else{
  precioo=document.getElementById('doblef').value;
 }
total=total+precioo;
} 
document.getElementById('llegadaa').innerHTML =total;  
}
```

```html
 <body onload="diferencia();">
 <input type="hidden" name="inicial" id="inicial"  value="'.$llegada.'" >
              <input type="hidden" name="final" id="final"  value="'.$salida.'" >
              
 <input type="hidden" name="dobleentre" id="dobleentre" value="'.$f['preciodobleentre'].'"> 
              <input type="hidden" name="doblef" id="doblef" value="'.$f['preciodoblef'].'"> 
              <span id="llegadaa">
```

Comment: No será porqué te toma el valor como string y necesitas convertirlo a int? Porque si tu somas 2 cadenas, te las va a concatenar no a sumar por ejemplo '32'+'53' = 3253

Comment: estas concatenando no sumando, debes hacer el parseInt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que la función `document.getelementbyid().value` retorna por defecto una variable de tipo texto. Para convertirla en un entero debes agregar un signo más (+) al principio. En tu caso sería algo así:

```
precioo = +document.getElementById('doblef').value;
```

Otra alternativa utilizar el método `parseInt`:

```
precioo = parseInt(document.getElementById('doblef').value);
```

Cualquiera de las 2 debería funcionar.

Comment: Muchas gracias, eso fue :)